# If condition for comparison between two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Am new to python programming. Can anyone pls check the below syntax for if condition-

```
if df1[A]<= df2[B]):
       print("")
else:
       print("")
```

**Getting this exception** - 
*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

Comment: There is a bracket you close, but never opened?

Comment: It seems you need `any` - `(df1[A]<= df2[B]).any()`

Comment: Apologies for being syntactically wrong. Yes there is a parenthesis '('

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You compare arrays, no scalar, so output of camparing is another array. So need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html). Also need length of both `Series` is same:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})
print (df1)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[1,2,0]})
print (df2)
   B
0  1
1  2
2  0

print (df1['A']<= df2['B'])
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

#check if at least one True
print ((df1['A']<= df2['B']).any())
True

#check if all values are True
print ((df1['A']<= df2['B']).all())
False
```

```
if (df1['A']<= df2['B']).any():
       print("at least one value True")
else:
       print("no False values")
at least one value True

if (df1['A']<= df2['B']).all():
       print("all values True")
else:
       print("not all values True")

not all values True
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]})
print (df1)
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B':[1,2,3]})
print (df2)
   B
0  1
1  2
2  3

print (df1['A']<= df2['B'])
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool

#check if at least one True
print ((df1['A']<= df2['B']).any())
True

#check if all values are True
print ((df1['A']<= df2['B']).all())
True
```

```
if (df1['A']<= df2['B']).any():
       print("at least one value True")
else:
       print("no False values")

at least one value True

if (df1['A']<= df2['B']).all():
       print("all values True")
else:
       print("not all values True")

all values True
```

Comment: no more true. I am using v.19.2 and
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3]});
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'B':[2,2,3]});
df1 > df2;
gives an error "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects"

Comment: @lehalle - You need compare columns `print (df1['A'] > df2['B'])`