# Check if the value of a row of dataframe is not contained in the column of another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to check if the value of a row in one dataframe is not contained in a specific column of another dataframe throug an "if" conditional

If my dataframes are:

```
df1:
   col1 col2
0   a   e
1   b   f
2   c   g
3   d   h

df2:

   col1 col2
0   a   y
1   v   u
2   x   z
3   w   t
```

I want to iterate through every row in col1 in df1 and check if that value is not contained in col1 of df2

My current code is:

```
 for row, i in df1.iterrows():
    for row, j in df2.iterrows():
       if i.col1 not in j.col1:
          print("blu")
```

Right now the code will enter the if condition even though the value in col1 of df1 IS contained in col1 of df2

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas is best avoid loops with `iterrows`, because slow. So better is use very fast vectorized `pandas` or `numpy` functions.

If need check if not present in column - use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for invert boolean mask:

```
mask = ~df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)
print (mask)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

alternative solution is use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
mask = ~np.in1d(df1.col1,df2.col1)
print (mask)
[False  True  True  True]
```

---

If need check per rows use `!=` or [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html):

```
mask = df1.col1 != df2.col1
#same as 
#mask = df1.col1.ne(df2.col1)
print (mask)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
mask = df1.col1.values != df2.col1.values
print (mask)
[False  True  True  True]
```

And if new column by mask is possible use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['new'] = np.where(mask, 'a', 'b')
print (df1)
  col1 col2 new
0    a    e   b
1    b    f   a
2    c    g   a
3    d    h   a
```

Difference is better seen in a bit different `DataFrames`:

```
print (df1)
  col1 col2
0    a    e
1    b    f
2    c    g
3    d    h

print (df2)
  col1 col2
0    a    y
1    v    u
2    d    z <- change value to d
3    w    t


mask = df1.col1 != df2.col1
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

---

```
mask = ~df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Numpy solutions are obviously faster:

```
In [23]: %timeit (~df1.col1.isin(df2.col1))
The slowest run took 7.98 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 198 µs per loop

In [24]: %timeit (~np.in1d(df1.col1,df2.col1))
The slowest run took 9.25 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 42.5 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. All of the solutions work to determine if a value is in a column but when I try to use this with a conditional like "if" i get the following error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You need add any for chech if at least one value is true by `if mask.any(): print 'at least one True'`

Comment: Also better explain it [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071684/if-condition-for-comparison-between-two-dataframes-in-python) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `isin`

```
df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```