# Creating a new column depending on the equality of two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

l want to compare the values of two columns where I create a new column `bin_crnn`. I want 1 if they are equals or 0 if not.

```
# coding: utf-8
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',sep=',')

if df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value']:
    df['bin_crnn']=1
else:
    df['bin_crnn']=0
```

l got the following error

```
    if df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value']:
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 917, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need cast boolean mask to `int` with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['bin_crnn'] = (df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value']).astype(int)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'crnn_pred':[1,2,5], 'manual_raw_value':[1,8,5]})
print (df)
   crnn_pred  manual_raw_value
0          1                 1
1          2                 8
2          5                 5

print (df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value'])
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df['bin_crnn'] = (df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value']).astype(int)
print (df)
   crnn_pred  manual_raw_value  bin_crnn
0          1                 1         1
1          2                 8         0
2          5                 5         1
```

You get error, because if compare columns output is not scalar, but `Series` (`array`) of `True` and `False` values.

So need [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) or 
[`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for return scalar `True` or `False`.

I think better it explain [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42071828/2901002).

Answer (score 10):

One fast approach is to use np.where.

```
import numpy as np
df['test'] = np.where(df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value'], 1, 0)
```

Comment: Nice approach @Allen. Good Q/A here regarding that approach and the benefits of it vs. a list comprehension depending on data set size: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19913659/6163621

Comment: I thought similar questions must have been asked and answered before here. I will take a look at that thread. @pshep123

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop or if statement, just need to set a new column using a boolean mask.

```
df['bin_crnn'].loc[df['crnn_pred']==df['manual_raw_value']] = 1
df['bin_crnn'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way just using Pandas and not Numpy is

```
df['columns_are_equal'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['column_a'] ==x['column_b']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score -2):

You are comparing 2 columns, try this..

```
bin_crnn = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['crnn_pred'] == row['manual_raw_value']:
        bin_crnn.append(1)
    else:
        bin_crnn.append(0)
df['bin_crnn'] = bin_crnn
```